# Improve the filtering of non-alphabetical symbols using "ascii_letters"

Tags: python, string

I am removing all non-alphabetical symbols from the beginning of string as follows:

```
from string import ascii_letters

non_letter = ''.join(set(map(chr, range(128))) - set(ascii_letters))

mystring = '— — This is the description of'
mystring.lstrip(non_letter)
```

It works well in most cases that I need. However, in the above-shown example the output is `— — This is the description of`, i.e. the symbols `— —`  are not removed. How to fix it?

Comment: Please show the output from `print(non_letter)`.

Comment: @ack: I think that it's encoded in some way. Anyway, I get this `08(2|
#]!,$*<>.&%/}@:4 "=9;75 +~)-63?{1_\'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to substitute a chain of non alphabetical (Latin/ASCII) letters at the start of the string with the empty string:

```
import re

mystring = '— — This is the description of'
trimmed = re.sub(r"^[^a-zA-Z]*", "", mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `non_letter` definition only contains ASCII characters which are not letters. (You loop from 0 through 127 and pick out all characters which are not alphabetics.) But the characters you want to remove are not ASCII characters; their code points are above 127.

If you really want to target only the 7-bit ASCII range, preprocess the string to remove anything outside that range.

```py
pure_ascii(inputstring):
    return ''.join(l for l in inputstring if ord(l) < 128)
```

More generally, in this millennium, probably use Unicode character properties to really target the code points you *actually* want to target.